# Display categories on product page Opencart 3

Tags: php, twig, opencart, opencart-3

I need to display the names of categories with links and images on the product page to which it belongs. Thank you in advance

Comment: Post your code what you have tried?

Comment: Have answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/63098891/3187127

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display images of categories on the product page to which it belongs Opencart 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63097066/how-to-display-images-of-categories-on-the-product-page-to-which-it-belongs-open)